# I have Python version 3.10 and my command center is saying i don't have PIP

Tags: python, command

I thought version 3 has pip installed. Why is my command prompt giving me this message when I do `pip --version`?

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is the issue?

Comment: you need to add the python path to Environment Variables. For windows:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages

Comment: Microsoft windows 10 @AbdulNiyasPM

Comment: It depends on how you installed Python. `pip` is not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
py -m pip --version
```